# Remove post templates from the selection box menu when creating a single post

Tags: templates, single

I added some post templates(not coding, using block editor) and now I can't find any options to delete those unnecessary templates.

[image]

Comment: Is this a programming question or a user support question? Are you using a block based theme?

Comment: Yes, I am using elementor based theme. If there is any way of deleting these templates I want to know that. I dont know , it could be programming based or user support based way. Thanks .

Comment: I ask because general user support questions are offtopic here, this is a programming stack. If there is a way to do this by clicking in the user interface then you're best asking on the .org support forums